# Image is getting improperly rendered with inverted colors using itextpdf library

Tags: itext

I have an issue with Itextpdf rendering of image..I am trying to render a tiff image to pdf but the image is not getting rendered properly and the rendered image has got inverted colors.
Note:
I havent set the inverted property of image

This issue is happening for few tiff images.

I could not find any clue about fixing it.
Plz help me if anybody encountered similar issue.

thanks,
ntalluri

http://jump.fm/NXPHB

Answer (score 0):

TIFF is a "bad" image type to work with since it is not actually an encoding, but an image container. The inversion of colors could have something to do with the fact that TIFFs can be encoded using a little-endian encoding and big-endian encoding. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_Image_File_Format

My suggestion is either to re-encode the pictures to have consistent endians, or just use another format such as PNG.